# Duplicates in Binary Search Tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, treenode

I am currently working on an Assignment in Data Structure topic Binary Trees. On of the question is: a) Draw a binary search tree by inserting the below numbers from left to right.
[15,7,8,20,13,10,5,17,40, 60, 30,70,6,14,4]. I drew my graph already. Now the confusing part is inserting a new node 7 and 17 into the tree.
I did a few research and found out that you cannot have duplicates in a Binary Tree. Or is there another way?

Comment: Inserting duplicates in a BST is no problem.  You just consider them to be a tiny bit greater than or less than the preexisting nodes with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

A Binary Search Tree(BST) can store only distinct values and are ordered.

But, a Binary Tree's values are not said to be ordered and distinct. So, there can be a possibility of finding duplicates.

**While dealing with BST, a hash table can be used to store duplicate node values.**

Answer (score 0):

There're several strategies to handle duplicates (equal keys) in binary search tree, as propose in CLRS chapter 12 Problem 12-1:
-Keep a boolean flag x.b at node x, and set x to either x.left or x.right based
on the value of x.b, which alternates between False and True each time we
visit x while inserting a node with the same key as x.

-Keep a list of nodes with equal keys at x, and insert z into the list.

-Randomly set x to either x.left or x.right.

Another strategy is to store a counter to every tree node, and increment this counter for each duplicate. You can find code implementation for this strategy here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-duplicates-in-binary-search-tree/